# How to rid punctuation in this file

Tags: python

I want to print out an index with no punctuation in it! I don't know what function is allowing my program to keep adding punctuation to the end of my words. My file also prints out what line number these words can be found in the text file that we are printing out.

```
    def makeIndex(filename):
        wordIndex = {}
        with open(filename) as f:
            lineNum = 1
            for line in f:
                words = line.lower().split()
                for word in words:
                    if word in wordIndex.keys():
                        if lineNum not in wordIndex[word]:
                            wordIndex[word].append(lineNum)
                    else:
                        wordIndex[word] = [lineNum]
                lineNum += 1
        return wordIndex

    def output(wordIndex):
        print("Word\tLine Numbers")
        for key in sorted(wordIndex.keys()):
            print(key, '\t', end=" ")
            for lineNum in wordIndex[key]:
                print(lineNum, end=" ")
            print()

def main():
    filename = input("What is the file name to be indexed?")
    index = makeIndex(filename)
    output(index)
```

main()

```
Output:
What is the file name to be indexed?test.txt
Word    Line Numbers
a    1 3 8 
all      9 10 
also     9 
an   3 10 
anagrams,    9 
anagrams.    10 
as   9 
ask      3 
blocks   1 
called   7 
create   8 
different    7 
difficulties     6 
each     8 
employed     7 
figure   3 
file     1 
find     10 
finds    9 
following    2 
for      2 8 
given    3 
has      8 
have     6 
here     7 
in   1 6 
interesting      2 
is   6 7 
it   10 
its      4 9 
jumble   2 
large    1 
letters.     4 
long     6 
many     6 
new      1 
of   1 4 6 9 10 
one      6 
opens    1 
out      3 
permutations.    7 9 
possibilities    2 
problem      6 
program      2 9 
programs.    2 
puzzles,     3 
range    1 
reorderings,     7 
same     8 
scrambled    3 
set      4 
signature    8 
since    9 
so   6 8 
solver   3 
solves   2 
solving      6 
strategy     7 
text     1 
that     6 8 
the      2 3 6 7 8 
this     6 9 
to   3 7 
typing   9 
unique   8 
unknown      3 
unscrambled      10 
up   1 
which    3 
whole    1 
will     10 
with     1 
word     3 8 10 
word,    8 
words    6 
working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the punctuation before you build your `wordIndex` dictionary.

e.g.

```
from string import punctuation

...
for word in words:
  for char in punctuation:
    word = word.replace(char, '')
  if word in wordIndex.keys():
```